# Long running web service call

Tags: android, performance, api

I have to call a web service from my android application where I have to post some parameters and then the server will start its operation. This operation will take around 10 minutes to complete.

What is the best way to handle this situation?

how to handle UI for these 10 minutes?
Will normal `AsyncTask` work in this situation? or I need to take any other approach?

Are there any libraries available which help in these kind of scenarios?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do this by using GCM too. Once server will finish its work it will inform you with notification.

Comment: Use  Service to do your task .

Answer (score 0):

You can show progress dialog while AsyncTask is working, but it is not a good way.

Another way, create background service to handle tasks.

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Answer (score 0):

Add background service for long running tasks. And after getting response; update the UI or cache it for future use.

Answer (score 0):

compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
Volley -> http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Answer (score 0):

You should use Service for long running background tasks. Use WeakReference<> for avoiding memory leaks